# Multiple java versions

Tags: redhat, java, classpath

I have a server running rhel5 and jre 1.6. All my apps are running perfectly for now. But I want to install java 1.7 but keeping java 1.6 as the default so my running apps want be affected. If I want to install java 1.7 from a rpm how can I do this, and how can I run a my new app with the new version of java without changing default java version

Answer (score 3):

Install the java versions you want, running applications should not be affected despite the default java version being changed.
Then run the `alternatives` utility to pick your default java version:

```
alternatives --config java
alternatives --config javac
```

Verify your setup with

```
java -version
javac -version
```

If you're unsure, try this on a non-production host first.

*Edit*:
To force tomcat to use a specific java version, no matter what the default, 
place a `setenv.sh` in tomcat's `bin` directory containing

```
JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698913/how-to-set-java-home-in-tomcat-config

Comment: In addition to alternatives --config java, for jdk you must run alternatives --config javac to choose which jdk environment you want to run your application in.

Comment: Problem is, even though my running apps use older java version I want to run only tomcat from a newer java version. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ivcode I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all install **Java 7/8** using:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Then you need to update alternatives using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

You will see:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1062      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Chose one that you need and type:

```
java -version
```

Then you can run your app on Java 7 and after that rollback it to 6 version.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make sure that your java apps are running thier java/javac from an absolute path.
now the default java is the java you have when you execute:

```
# java -version
```

every java app you want to run must specify the absolute path according to your needs.
to change the default execute:

```
# which java
```

and find out where is your default java bin is located and change the link to your designated jdk